# Replace same strings with swap difference?

Tags: tcl

To manipulate Strings in Tcl, we use the string command.

If you need to replace comma:

```
set value { 10.00 }
puts [string map -nocase { . , }  $value]

# Return: 10,00
```

We can replace several strings:

```
set text "This is a replacement test text"
puts [string map -nocase { e E s S a A } $text]

# Returns: THIS IS A TEXT OF REPLACEMENT TEST
```

Of course, we can replace words:

```
set text "This is a replacement test text"
puts [string map -nocase {test TEST a {second}} $text]

# Returns: This is the second replacement TEST text.
```

---

So far so good!

But one question that does not want to be silent is .. **How to replace more than one identical occurrence in the sentence, giving a DIFFERENT substitution for each of them?**

## For example:

```
set time {10:02:12}
puts [string map -nocase { { : +} {: =} } $time]
```

> I would like this result: **10 + 02 = 12**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
proc seqmap {str match args} {
    set rc $str
    foreach l [lreverse [regexp -all -indices -inline ***=$match $str]] \
      replacement [lreverse $args] {
        set rc [string replace $rc {*}$l $replacement]
    }
    return $rc
}

seqmap 10:02:12 : { + } { = }
```

=> 10 + 02 = 12

I'm using `lreverse` in case the replacement has a different length than the string it replaces. The indices would be off if the replacements were done from left to right.

The `***=` is used to avoid special treatment of wildcard characters in the match string.

Of course, things get a lot more complicated if you want to handle the case where the number of occurrences doesn't match the number of provided substitutions. And even more if you want to replace several different strings.

---

This version handles the complications mentioned above:

```
proc seqmap {map str} {
    # Transform the map into a dict with each key containing a list of replacements
    set mapdict {}
    foreach {s r} $map {dict lappend mapdict $s $r}
    # Build a map where each key maps to a unique tag
    # At the same time build a dict that maps our tags to the replacements
    # First map the chosen tag character in case it is present in the string
    set newmap {@ @00}
    set mapdict [dict map {s r} $mapdict {
        lappend newmap $s [set s [format @%02d [incr num]]]
        set r
    }]
    # Add the tag character to the dict so it can be mapped back
    dict set mapdict @00 @
    # Map the tags into the string
    set rc [string map $newmap $str]
    # Locate the positions where the tags ended up
    set match [regexp -all -indices -inline {@\d\d} $rc]
    # Create a list of replacements matching the tags
    set replace [lmap l $match {
        # Extract the tag
        set t [string range $rc {*}$l]
        # Obtain a replacement for this tag
        set s [lassign [dict get $mapdict $t] r]
        # Return the used replacement to the end of the list
        dict set mapdict $t [linsert $s end $r]
        # Add the replacement to the list
        set r
    }]
    # Walk the two lists in reverse order, replacing the tags with the selected replacements
    foreach l [lreverse $match] r [lreverse $replace] {
        set rc [string replace $rc {*}$l $r]
    }
    # Done
    return $rc
}
```

You call it just like you would `string map`, so with a key-value mapping and the string to perform the replacements on. Any duplicated keys specify the subsequent values to be substituted for each occurrence of the key. When the list is exhausted it starts over from the beginning.

So `puts [seqmap {: + : = : *} 10:02:12]` => 10+02=12

And `puts [seqmap {: + : =} 10:02:12:04:16]` => 10+02=12+04=16

As presented, the command can handle up to 99 unique keys. But it can easily be updated if more are needed.

Comment: Cool, I'm looking into the source code of your answer ... sounds good to me.

Comment: It is quite a lot easier to do this in 8.7, which has `regsub -command`.